# Can anyone identify this LCD Display

Tags: lcd, identification, display

How do I go about identifying an LCD display module so I can get a data sheet?

16 Pins to one side in 2 rows of 8.

printed on PCB: hy-211
printed on PCB: v0022201 rev.b

printed on a sticker on side: 2220stldygbn-0   255

No other identifying marks on PCB

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you share a link to a picture? Someone with 10 credits will edit it in for you.

Comment: only could share 2 links, but you get the idea for the last 2! add "https"

Comment: Have a thought of searching for “2220stldygbn” on the web cross your mind? “Vikay” shows up as a first result in Google...

Comment: If you crop the images to contain only the interesting part, I'm happy to link them in the question.

Comment: http://www.wrighthobbies.com/datasheets/VK2220.pdf

Comment: sorry vlad new to this thing.

Answer (score 2):

That would be a [Vikay](http://www.vikay.com/index2.html) 2220 STN LED-backlit yellow/green LCD module meant to be viewed from below.

Comment: thanks, where could i get a datasheet?

Comment: "Specs available upon request"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a standard [Hitachi HD44780 LCD controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller) compatible dislay. The Internet is full with code examples for various microcontrollers or development boards.

The hardware specs are in the [datasheet](http://www.wrighthobbies.com/datasheets/VK2220.pdf) that [you linked in the comments](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72544/can-anyone-identify-this-lcd-display/72549#comment139941_72544).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple 16x2 LCD screen.It also have 16 pins.parallel data pins from D0 to D7,power pins for LCD 2,contrast pin V0(1),Enable,register read/write,command/data,2 pins for background LED's.Search internet on 16x2 LCD screen pinout.Some LCD will have pins on top,some may have pins on the side of the screen. Search accordingly.